# Solve for $x$ : $\sqrt{3x^{-2}-2}=2x-1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Solve for $x$:

$$\sqrt{3x^{-2}-2}=2x-1$$

I got $x=(1, -1,\frac{1}{2})$ but $-1$ or $\frac{1}{2}$ does not solve the equation

Please help me solve it...

Comment: The $-1$ comes from the fact that you squared both sides without imposing the consistency conditions (or whatever they're called). The $\frac12$ comes from some mistake of algebra.

Comment: Welcome to the MathSE community! Guess you're collecting downvotes because your post is practically  not  readable. Which is quasi-equivalent to being not properly formatted (in LaTeX, via using MathJax).

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would do it. It might not be a rigorous answer but [WolframAlpha agrees with my conclusion](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%20%5Csqrt(3x%5E(-2)-2)%3D2x-1)

\begin{align}\sqrt{3x^{-2}-2}&=2x-1\\
3x^{-2}-2&=(2x-1)^2\tag{square both sides}\\
3x^{-2}-2&=4x^2-4x+1\tag{expand bracket}\\
\frac{3}{x^2}-2&=4x^2-4x+1\tag{meaning of $x^{-2}$}\\
\frac{3}{x^2}&=4x^2-4x+3\\
3&=4x^4-4x^3+3x^2\tag{multiply by $x^2$}\\
4x^4-4x^3+3x^2-3&=0\tag{set equal to $0$}\\
(x-1)(4x^3+3x+3)&=0\tag{trial and error to find factor}\\
\implies x&=1
\end{align}